# CreateFile returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED despite FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS

Tags: winapi, backup, ntfs, shadow-copy

I am developing a Windows backup application (mixed Go / C++) that needs to backup files from the disk.

My application

1. runs as a user in the "Backup Operators" group, and also with "Back up files and directories" explicitly enabled in `secpol.msc`
2. calls `OpenProcessToken()` and `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` to grant `SeBackupPrivilege` for the whole process, successfully
3. takes a VSS snapshot of the disk, successfully
4. walks over all files in the VSS snapshot, and then tries to back them up as follows:

   `CreateFile(
       path,
       GENERIC_READ,
       FILE_SHARE_READ,
       NULL, // SecurityAttributes
       OPEN_EXISTING,
       FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS|FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN
       NULL // TemplateFile
   );`
5. Calls `BackupRead()` to read file streams.

This normally works fine, and I can successfully read files for which my user account would normally be denied read access to (e.g. `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`).

**But despite this**, some "stubborn" files still give an error, from `CreateFile`: 0x5 `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` ("Access is Denied").

I know the "stubborn" files aren't reparse points.

The files exist on a local, internally-attached, SATA, NTFS disk drive - not a network drive or anything exotic.

The "stubborn" files are all files, not directories.

They are a range of file-types (docx, fla, swf, .DS_Store, ...).

There's no special security software installed other than an Antivirus program.

A competititor's backup software is able to back up these files without error.

*Why could this possibly be happening?*

Comment: call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead `GetLastError()` on fail. which will be status ?

Comment: if the file is deeply embedded in a folder structure or has weird chars in the file name, you might need POSIX_SEMANTICS to get it.

Comment: Another possibility is that the file was moved/deleted with MoveFileEx and the move/delete is pending a reboot

Comment: The POSIX semantics flag is nearly useless except for allowing `CreateFile` to be able to create a directory. With the default system configuration (since Windows XP), it doesn't even allow case-sensitive opening. It doesn't allow "weird chars" in the name, and doesn't even bypass normal DOS path normalization (as is possible with the "\\?\" prefix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be caused by an EFS-encrypted file, for which no key is present.

In this situation `CreateFile` is not possible under any circumstance.